# How to call payumoney function in customized page?

Tags: magento-1.7

[image]I have redirected to payment method and then while placing order what are the required parameters to pass in Payment Method. Here I only have amount value. I am not placing any order.

Comment: have you created custom payment method or add any custom extension?

Comment: @Abdul - Placing order for products we use payment method as shown in screenshot.

Comment: looks like you are using ccavenue or payumoney? is it?

Comment: @same payumoney

Comment: check it -  https://github.com/payumoney-india/

Comment: Check here readymat module available for this: https://www.payumoney.com/payment-gateway-integration-guide.html

Comment: @Abdul thank u so much, I will check and let u know